# Kubernetes Ingress ROOT Path to Different Service

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I would like to route certain paths of my host to a different backend.

Assuming I have 2 backend services:

- backend-one
- backend-two

All of the requests were routed to `backend-one` initially, like in the example below.

```
rules:
    - host: example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            backend:
              serviceName: backend-one
              servicePort: 3000
```

Now, I have `backend-two` as the new service, which should be serving content for specific paths, but most importantly the `/` (root) page as well.

So, my goal would be the following:

- Paths `/`, `/abc`, `/xyz`, `/12345` to be served by ====> `backend-two` (the new service).
- Everything else to be served by `backend-one` the old service.

What would be the simplest approach for achieving this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

As per Kubernetes [CHANGELOG-1.18.md](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/CHANGELOG/CHANGELOG-1.18.md#extending-ingress-with-and-replacing-a-deprecated-annotation-with-ingressclass):

> In Kubernetes 1.18, there are two significant additions to Ingress: A
> new `pathType` field and a new `IngressClass` resource. The `pathType`
> field allows specifying how paths should be matched. In addition to
> the default `ImplementationSpecific` type, there are new `Exact` and
> `Prefix` path types.

You can use Kubernetes 1.18+ with [Path types](https://v1-18.docs.kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/ingress/#path-types) to achieve what you want. Use the following config:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress
spec:
  rules:
  - host: example.com
    http:
      paths:
      # Proxy to backend-two when the request is EXACT the root path
      - path: /
        pathType: Exact
        backend:
          serviceName: backend-two
          servicePort: 3000
      # Proxy specic paths (including subpaths) to backend-two
      - path: /abc
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          serviceName: backend-two
          servicePort: 3000
      - path: /xyz
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          serviceName: backend-two
          servicePort: 3000
      - path: /12345
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          serviceName: backend-two
          servicePort: 3000
      # If no rules above match, Proxy to backend-one
      - path: /
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          serviceName: backend-one
          servicePort: 3000
```

Remember that you can also use [Regular Expressions](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/#regular-expression-support) to improve your Ingress config in case you have multiple paths to handle.

Comment: This is amazing and exactly what I need! Thanks Eduardo!

Comment: Hi @AndreiGaspar glad it worked. Please note that the preferred way of saying 'thanks' around here is by up-voting good questions and helpful answers (once you have enough reputation to do so), and by accepting the most helpful answer to any question you ask (which also gives you a small boost to your reputation). Please see the [About] page, and [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)